# Giving feedback to someone without sounding prejudiced

Tags: feedback, discrimination, sexism

I had this situation at work where a colleague (not my report, but junior to me by 5~10 years) was pushing people so strongly to work on a project that it caused a few of those people and their managers to come to me and either complain outright about it or just express confusion about it, because they hadn't heard about who this junior person was.

I felt like I owed this colleague to share the feedback that I was seeing a pattern that could be detrimental to their career and shared it, specifically pointing at instances and offering suggestions.

Here's the problem. I'm a man, that colleague is a woman, and I work in an industry (as many) where women have reason to complain of multiple biases. I was very conscious that my feedback could come off as sexist, so if anything, I held back until I saw more of a pattern, and made a very conscious effort to focus on the specifics without using any adjectives to describe her personally -- I said things like "in this case, you did this, and the outcome was that, here's how it could become a problem for you in the long term, and here's a couple things you can consider doing in the future", nothing at all like "you're being too aggressive". She thanked me for that feedback, shared some of her own, and I thought that feedback session went well.

Still, a couple days after sharing this, she told me that the conversation made her feel like I was basically just a man telling a woman to shut up.

I felt very sad hearing that because in reality I am completely rooting for her and want her to succeed, and her questions are making it very uncomfortable, if not dangerous career-wise, for me to help her by sharing insights.

I pointed out that I had seen a pattern not a single instance, that I had "checked my biases", that in fact a few of the people complaining were women too, and that she could do whatever she wanted with that feedback. I don't know if she was genuinely convinced but we left it at that. Not a pleasant experience.

So here's my question. What more can I do to give feedback to someone and completely avoid giving the false impression that my feedback comes from prejudice? (And replace gender by race/ethnicity/age/religion/sexual orientation etc...)

EDIT

A couple clarifications addressing some of the things in the comments or replies.

- I had discussed the situation with this person's manager, who had encouraged me to share feedback and help coach her rather than he having to do it with secondhand information.
- The person didn't argue that gender bias was a reason to dismiss my feedback. She acknowledged the feedback I gave her, just said it made her feel a certain way, which both of us disliked.

EDIT 2

For my first question, I am overwhelmed with gratitude at this community for the amount of thoughtful discussion. Thank you all.

I also want to explain the answer that I'll accept, because the topic is obviously contentious, answers are a bit all over the place and because the one that I've personally found the most useful is by far not the one with the highest "popular vote". I'll go over the most popular answers and my thoughts on them first.

Old Nick's answer is relevant, but not a direct answer to my question; its main argument is that I shouldn't give feedback directly to a person who does not report to me. Even if that were true, I will be confronted to situations where dodging the responsibility of giving feedback is not an option, and then it won't help me.

ShinEmperor's answer construes the situation as one where I have given "advice" to the person, and then argues against giving advice in general. But there is a big difference between advice (where I have nothing at stake in the other person's behavior) and feedback (where I do). This situation had affected me because it destabilized my team, so doing nothing also had a cost to me; I had skin in the game to defend.

I generally agree with bilbo_pingouin and Words_like_jared's answers, but instead of giving me thoughts on what I could have done differently, they focus on what I should do from now on.

So in the end, it was in Erika's answer that I have found the most interesting clue about something I could have done differently, which is to *ask questions* in the first place. I was certainly focused on giving feedback, and I can see how asking questions instead might have helped in this situation. The answer is slightly off-base in other respects due to the vagueness of the context in my question (i.e. the answer makes it sound like it was someone pushing a pet project, which it wasn't) but I'll accept it as the most useful to me personally.

Again thanks everyone for the thoughtful discussion and answers.

Comment: @ShinEmperor I'm acting very consciously here

Comment: Why did her colleagues come to you with their feedback and not to somebody she reports to and not straight to her?

Comment: Holding back because she's a woman is sexist, not the other way around. read: You hold back _because_ of her sex.

Comment: @Will Probably for the same reason people post on Workplace instead of proceeding directly to boss / manager / HR / lawyer.  They weren't sure what to do.  They were annoyed but didn't want to cause a fuss.  etc.  The same reasons that you have talked to coworkers casually instead of starting formal actions.

Comment: *a colleague (not my report, but junior to me by 5~10 years)* - Are you on the same team or in the same department? What was your relationship to this colleague before you had the initial conversation?

Comment: @DaveG making an informal comment to a manager is not any more of a "formal action" than making an informal comment to a non-report about their professional performance (although describing it as a "feedback session" is enough to raise concerns on its own that this wouldn't be a professional way to handle this situation irrespective of gender-related concerns)

Comment: *...and their managers to come to me...* So your colleague is actually below you in the hierarchy? You're **a** manager, just not **her** manager? If not, why are managers coming to you to complain about her? I can understand peers doing it if DaveG is correct in that they're just blowing off steam but it's weird for managers to also do that unless you're a manager too.

Comment: Did you ask/could you ask this particular person how she might have preferred the information be expressed (if at all) by you? Biases are really tricky to work around, there's no guarantee that any amount of effort from you will be successful, and you can't include in the question details about the interaction which you didn't notice. Asking her directly is almost certainly the only way to get information definitely practical for the specific situation you described. So is that an option, or do you need the best "general case" answer people can come up with?

Comment: *I had "checked my biases"* - Remember - you're not the only one with biases.

Comment: @Will the people who came to me did so because I work with them much more frequently than with her.

Comment: @BSMP I'm a manager indeed just not hers

Comment: *her questions are making it very uncomfortable, if not dangerous career-wise, for me to help her by sharing insights* - What questions?

Comment: @BSMP sorry that wasn't clear. her questioning of my motives.

Comment: Is it common practice in your workplace to receive feedback from unrelated managers? Did she know you before this happened? Are you sure that it was a reproach, not a frank feedback?

Comment: Well I have a instructor, who is basicly human trash (Not only to me, but to almost everyone). But in most discussions he is right and that's backing him. As Compensation we're jokng behind his back about him. That makes it endurable. Soooo the moral of this story is have fun, dont let others drag you down.

Comment: Why are these people coming to you to deliver the feedback when this woman is not your report? Why didn't you direct them to the woman's actual manager? The other manager's excuse of "having to do it with secondhand information" seems... lame. You are doing it with secondhand information, why can't he... especially when it's HIS job? It seems like he was using you to dodge a bullet.

Comment: @JeffC Yes.  This is what I was thinking.  It's the manager's job to deliver this kind of feedback.  She still might not like it, but it at least it would be part of the normal work procedure.

Comment: @barbsan yes it is common and she knew me from before. Not sure about your question regarding reproach.

Comment: You may want to approach her and ask to talk about the interaction and what was problematic for her, BUT, only do this if you are genuinely open to the possibility that you did something less than ideal. You seem entirely convinced that you are blameless and she is wrong to react the way she did, and that is not the basis for a constructive conversation about this. I think you should consider the possibility that, as a man, you maybe are not the total expert on sexism and how it plays out, and there might be something you could learn from her if you're open to learning it.

Comment: @qoba How much rapport and/or trust would you say existed between the two of you _prior_ to you trying to give your feedback? Also, given that this person has already 'red pilled' you with that veiled/implied threat (saying you're being "sexist" and the implication of potential HR involvement, you feeling you and your career are threatened, etc) I'd be more careful about future interactions and _avoid_ private 1-1 settings. You already feel threatened; keep your options in mind, even HR; this person's reaction is creating a hostile work environment.

Comment: If there is another female in your group that could have given the feedback it may have been more helpful either for her to give it, or both of you with the other female leading the conversation.

Comment: @Dana _"You may want to approach her and ask to talk about the interaction..."_ I think this would be a mistake. Given the current precedent, there's no reason to believe that she wouldn't escalate the situation and make more serious claims (e.g. claiming to HR that she's being "oppressed", or "harassed", etc.). I see no good reason to tell OP to put himself at risk here... even if OP did that with witnesses, I don't see how it makes anything better (e.g. she could claim that the effort is "systemic" b/c multiple other people were present). She's clearly taking all of that _very_ differently.

Comment: @DavidBaucum _"another female in your group that could have given the feedback"_ Why should anyone need a female employee before giving feedback to a female? That's an arbitrary standard that comes across as "sexist" as the female colleague is being. OP needs to apply the same standard to everyone, regardless of gender. As Peter Staff already mentioned, giving this female employee special treatment is sexist, and it's also unfair to other employees, b/c they're being held to different standards.

Comment: @PeterPaff The way I read it, the OP is holding back because they're deathly afraid of being sexist or of being accused of it. That isn't sexism; that's awareness of the hypersensitive, prejudice-accusation-happy culture we live in.

Comment: So someone pulled some whatever discrimination card on you, and you are feeling bad for doing your job?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro no, not the case at all. Feel free to read my other comments about it, the situation is a lot more nuanced than "pulling a discrimination card"

Comment: @code_dredd, because when you are doubling down to make sure that you are both not accidently being misogynist and not having the appearance of misogyny then you take the steps that will be helpful to both goals.

Comment: @DavidBaucum You need to realize that you're effectively creating a _double standard_ for this person solely based on gender differences, which is contrary to your stated intention. A key issue, IMHO, is the colleague's _subjective perception_ of the situation; it doesn't seem to correlate to _objective_ reality. _If_ she believes that _any_ man giving _any_ feedback she may not want to hear is "oppressive", then it _doesn't matter_ what/how OP does b/c OP isn't the problem; rather, it'd be her trying to have it both ways (i.e. "equality" and special treatment). That's a separate problem.

Comment: @code_dredd if that special treatment gave her special access, or more leeway then it could be problematic. The nice thing about just shifting the criticism being given be a woman is that it doesn't really advantage her in any way to have the woman deliver the message over a man doing it. It only takes away the potential appearance of sexism.

Comment: @DavidBaucum _"shifting the criticism being given by a woman ... only takes away the potential appearance of sexism"_ You're probably right on that. I guess my point is that it shouldn't have to be that way.

Comment: @qoba you sound like a really cool human being. congratulations on that :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider approaching the original feedback conversation from a stance of humbleness and seeking to understand.

> ...a colleague was pushing people so strongly to work on a project
>   that it caused a few of those people and their managers to come to me
>   and either complain outright about it or just express confusion about
>   it, because they hadn't heard about who this junior person was.

This strikes me as someone who is ambitious, and feels strongly about the success of the company. Who in turn is being repeatedly rejected. If this is something you wish to better understand, consider facilitating the conversation with variants of the following questions:

> I notice you’ve been pushing for project X. Why do you see such value
>   in it? How do you feel it will benefit the company? <allow & listen to
>   answer, drawing out as needed>
>
> Its been a few (weeks, months) since you first suggested project X, but
>   you’re still bringing it up. What reasons have you been given for us
>   not taking on project X?  < allow answering; if she hasn’t had any reasons, why not? this is
>   something to discuss with your colleagues about> Why do you still feel project X
>   should be done despite these reasons?

At this stage, suggesting future approaches for proposing and getting projects accepted at your company would be valueable.

She has demonstrated a desire to be proactive, and I imagine is frustrated at being shut down. As a junior employee, consider offering mentorship,  or discuss with your colleagues about having a mentorship system for new employees. She has likely demonstrated the technical expertise for her position, but as a junior its hardly fair to expect her to master or understand factors at play in your firm for project decisions.

**Edit:** I'm unclear whether she wanted to be added to an existing project, or was proposing the company work on a specific project. Written in the context of the latter, but could be equally answered for the former - with the addendum of her exploring what skills would be required to move to the existing project if that is something she wants in her career - again, mentorship regarding the process is of value here.

Comment: How would this approach solve the problem of coworkers complaining about this colleague pushing a particular project?  She doesn't need to convince the OP, he's not going to be working on the project.  She needs to change her approach to her coworkers to motivate them to work on the project.  The OP gave her some suggestions on how to approach that issue, and she somehow felt put down by that.

Comment: She was working on a project that we all agree is important.

Comment: @DaveG I thought the problem asked was how to provide feedback without sounding prejudice. I’m suggesting approaching the conversation from a stance of understanding her perspective, helping her understand the company’s perspective, and considering establishing a mentorship. Such reframing of the conversation - more discussion-based, less top-down - may have been recieved differently.

Comment: @Erika That's a good point.  However, it's still true that regardless of how the conversation on project importance goes, the OP has to deliver some difficult feedback.  Understanding the importance of the project doesn't change the feedback.  After reading a bunch of answers and the OP's comments, I'm thinking the OP should have simply passed this back to her manager to deliver the feedback, so it would come in the normal flow of work.

Comment: I like inviting a conversation much better then making feedback her bosses problem. What's missing here is support. If people are coming to the OP asking who she is and what this project is then, as a leader, the OP should introduce her around and introduce others to the project and the idea that she's working on it. That way she doesn't feel like a door to door salesman every time she has to ask someone for help.

Comment: *She was working on a project that we all agree is important.* @qoba - The more info you reveal in the comments, the more I suspect that the problem is at least as much about the context in which the conversation occurred as anything you actually said.

Comment: @Erika _"I thought the problem asked was how to provide feedback without sounding prejudice"_ The problem, as I see it, is not the OP's way of _giving_ feedback, but the female colleague's way of _taking_ feedback. She's getting feedback from a peer (i.e. same level at company, not a supervisor/whatever) that's actually looking out for her (more than he is for his other colleagues, simply b/c she's a woman...)  and _her_ reaction is to claim she feels "oppressed" by OP b/c he's a man... I think most are advising OP on the wrong thing. He doesn't seem to be the problem here.

Comment: @code_dredd There may be other problems in this situation, and in the world in general, and I'm not discounting that my peer has some areas for improvement of her own, but what Erika said was really the question I was asking. In fact this answer is one of the few that directly answers my question and not some other thing.

Comment: @qoba Then good luck with the situation.

Answer (score 147):

As long as you kept your feedback limited to the things she did, what the effect of those things were and what she could do to get a better outcome I don't see how anything you have said could be construed as being related in any way to her gender.

She has tried to make it about gender, not you because she has taken it personally and to be fair as you are not her manager you should have probably not tried to act like one (I know you tried to give friendly advice but this is not how she seems to have taken it).

In future, you'd be better off directing anybody who has any questions about her to her reporting manager "XXX doesn't report to me sorry, you're better off raising it with her personally or her manager.".

Comment: +1 for the redirect. Absolutely the correct thing to do

Comment: +1 for pointing out the deviation to gender. It's a defense mechanism to divert the discussion or attempt to explain something negative out of ones control if no arguments are found against what has been said.

Comment: In other words, she is being sexist, not you.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Agreed. The junior colleague is wondering: "Why is this person giving me detailed feedback on my shortcomings when they are not my boss?" The feedback was unwelcome whether it was well meaning or not.

Comment: *"I don't see how anything you have said could be construed as being related in any way to her gender"* - unfortunately, it's pretty much always possible to construe basically any social interaction between people of different genders as being about gender, if you're minded to do so. *"In future [direct people] to her reporting manager"* - might be sound advice to protect the OP, but highlights a key danger of protesting that you're receiving sexist treatment: to avoid the allegation, people must henceforth *actually* treat you differently from others.

Comment: Honestly, if the OP were to conclude he was sexist after all it ought to come to a relief to him, because the alternative is learning that even *without* any motivating biases his handling of office gossip and performance concerns among his colleagues is prone to being unconstructive and unprofessional.

Comment: I don't think she has "tried to make it about gender" in the sense of deflecting the advice; she has acknowledged that the feedback was valuable. But she has perceived this to be potentially about gender in spite of my best efforts.

Comment: *I don't see how anything you have said...* - This doesn't make sense. We don't know what the OP said because it isn't in the question.

Comment: @qoba You said "she told me that the conversation made her feel like I was basically just a man telling a woman to shut up" . Unless there was anything else in the conversation you haven't told us where you've referred to her gender then she absolutely has made this about gender. Anyway, my answer still stands - To avoid situations like this in future let that persons direct report handle things like this.

Comment: @OldNick she has expressed her feelings, that's all. I understand this has a lot of upvotes but I don't really understand what redirecting to her manager has to do with my question. If this person had been my direct report, I would still have had that issue but then even worse because it wouldn't have been optional for me to share the feedback. I don't think this answer actually addresses the real question -- I asked "how to do X" and this says "you didn't have to do X in this case"

Comment: @qoba Let me put it in a more straight-forward way then, avoid giving feedback to people you don't manage, leave that to their managers and you won't make them feel defensive and only give this kind of feedback to people who report to you. I thought that was clear from my answer, apologies it not & best wishes as it's obvious you had good intentions and were saddened by what happened later.

Comment: I highly suspect her attitude is carefully honed as a result of years of men telling her to shut up for no other reason than because she's a woman. Thanks to the efforts of previous wolf-criers, now when there's legitimate feedback intended to help her and her career, she dismisses it as more of the same. I can't say I rightly blame her.

Comment: @OldNick I appreciate this. Aside from the fact that it's common and expected in my work environment to share feedback with people we don't directly manage, I may at some point find myself in a situation to share similar feedback with a direct report, in which case your answer wouldn't help.

Comment: @qoba If she was in fact reporting to you then it would be a different situation. Anyway, since you say this is common in your workplace then I don't have anything else to suggest.

Comment: +1 for the redirection. There's _no good reason_ for OP to further put himself and his career at risk of outright false claims (e.g. "harassment", "oppression", etc) from this other female employee. Let her sink her own ship on her own and watch from a distance. Her career suicide is not OP's problem and there's already a veiled threat against him b/c, in her mind, OP is being "sexist".

Comment: @code_dredd she hasn't claimed anything of the sort. Just expressed a feeling.

Comment: @qoba I didn't say that she had made those claims. I simply said that, given what has happened, there's reason to believe that it _could_ escalate as I described in other comments. Personally, I'd be careful, but power to you.

Comment: @code_dredd I agree and am being careful, just want to be clear that the situation has not escalated to this level at all

Comment: Since OP defends her acceptance of the advice here's an idea: maybe this isn't a workplace issue but an IPS one, maybe she isn't deflecting and OP just didn't know how to act in a gender-agnostic fashion. Just to add another possibility to the mix, since as mentioned in the question OP changed his behavior because the colleague was a woman.

Answer (score 27):

I responded to your post but I'll go ahead and answer:

> I felt like I owed this colleague to share the feedback that I was seeing a pattern that could be detrimental to their career and shared it, specifically pointing at instances and offering suggestions.

This, generally speaking, is not as helpful as people imagine it to be. Unsolicited criticism is rarely taken well. [Forbes covers this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/markmurphy/2015/10/13/why-giving-advice-doesnt-work/#1c659ea42e28), and it's kind of interesting.

Some key points:

> - When you give advice, in essence, you’re telling somebody else what to do. This implies you have all the answers about what works and what doesn’t. But how could you? Chances are you don’t have all the background information on the situation, nor do you understand the other person’s emotions and what makes them tick.
> - When you give advice, you offer the other party only two choices: take the advice or ignore the advice. And in either case, there’s the possibility of a “gotcha.” If your advice is taken, that means the other person must tacitly admit you’re right and he or she is wrong. This automatically gives you credit for being smarter. That’s Gotcha #1 and it’s a dangerous scenario, one that’s almost guaranteed to create defensiveness.
> - Most advice is unsolicited. This means the other party didn’t ask to be judged, corrected, or directed. When you catch someone off guard and hit them upside the head with advice; there’s virtually no chance they’ll be in an open emotional state to hear what you say. Listen, there are many ways to give feedback. Giving advice, though, often makes people defensive, comes off as arrogance or can just seem like a suggestion rather than a command. Constructive feedback can push good employees toward great performance, but advice generally just doesn’t work. And remember, while advice may be fun to give, it’s generally not that much fun to get.

All of these things played out in your description from her side. People will frame it as a "her being defensive and using gender to deflect" when in reality, unsolicited advice is the REAL issue here.

Then with the current political climate you get: [Mansplaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mansplaining)

> is a pejorative term meaning "(of a man) to comment on or explain something to a woman in a condescending, overconfident, and often inaccurate or oversimplified manner"

This is what you wrote:

> "in this case, you did this, and the outcome was that, here's how it could become a problem for you in the long term, and here's a couple things you can consider doing in the future"

Depending on tone... and the unsolicited nature of the advice, it could absolutely be Mansplaining.

Good Intentions, poorly thought out, can lead to a lot of trouble.

To be clear, I'm not saying it is a gender issue, but observing this from the perspective of a woman, who is new at her job and potentially struggling; to have a man just step in and start telling you what your faults are and how you can do better, feels... awkward? Something about it, to me, doesn't feel right.

What I did notice in your description, was interesting. There was a lot of effort put into avoiding looking bad, avoiding being blamed. There was also a lot of effort put into explaining what was wrong with what she has done.

But I didn't sense much empathy... There's no clarification of how much effort was made to understand her perspective in the organization? Gender might have zero to do with any of it, but it's clear this is a colleague who is struggling, but in turn is getting unsolicited advice rather than guidance...

Like this:

> I was very conscious that my feedback could come off as sexist, so if anything, I held back...
>
> I pointed out that I had seen a pattern not a single instance, that I had "checked my biases", that in fact a few of the people complaining were women too, and that she could do whatever she wanted with that feedback.

This isn't empathy... this is building a body of evidence... like an indictment... against a fellow colleague, which you then just came at her with, on your terms, not hers...

My response: Practice more empathy in your assessment. It's about more than clarity. It's about understanding the other person's perspective and understanding they experience the world in a different way.

UPDATE:

Just an afterthought...

> where a colleague (not my report, but junior to me by 5~10 years) was pushing people so strongly to work on a project

Does anyone know why? Why she was pushing people? Because from the description, it looks like zero effort was put into understanding the "why", what is motivating her? Someone else in the company? Is it her own directive?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91333/discussion-on-answer-by-shinemperor-giving-feedback-to-someone-without-sounding).

Comment: it was most likely received as "if I was a man i would be being call confident a leader, but as a woman I am pushy confusing people"

Comment: "unsolicited advice rather than guidance..." What difference do you see between the two? "This isn't empathy... this is building a body of evidence... like an indictment... against a fellow colleague, which you then just came at her with, on your terms, not hers..." Seems like a no-win situation to me. If they approach immediately, then they're jumping to conclusions. If they wait for more evidence, they're "building an indictment". And what does "on your terms not hers" mean? What, the OP should ask her when they should approach her?

Comment: @Acccumulation Guidance is an exchange between two willing participants. Unsolicited Advice is one person forcing guidance onto another person. Well, when someone takes it upon themselves to just offer up random guidance to people, of course it's a no-win. The OP approached her, and then gave his feedback. He wasn't her manager. He just decided to take it upon himself to "educate" her. That's explicitly on his terms. On her terms would look like this: OP: "Hey I'm ____, I'm a senior here. If you have any questions or need help, feel free to ask." Then it can be on her terms.

Comment: This is really the best answer. I'd emphasize the empathy a bit more though. It's a stereo-typically male response to try to solve problems, and the colleague's later feedback I read as honest feedback that should have been answered with "I'm so sorry, that's not at all how I intended it." And the colleague's manager should have introduced the feedback, turning it from "unsolicited advice" into "professional feedback you expect in a workplace."

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but could be further improved by suggesting that advice, when given, is offered via asking, not telling. It is very possible (we don't know, we weren't there!) that the OP's advice was along the lines of "I've noticed you've done X, you should have done Y". As you note, that kind of unsolicited advice will not always be well received. "When you did X, what do you think the consequences were? What do you think other people thought of it? Why did you do it in that way?" might be more successful, and an opening for the other person to actively ask for advice.

Comment: Why is empathy necessary at all? You can give critical feedback without being rude while not needing to be _empathetic_. Are you just using the term to mean "being polite"?

Comment: I did not mean polite, not even close. Empathy is about putting yourself in someone else's shoes and understanding how they see and understand the world. This is very powerful because it helps us contextualize how we talk and interact with people. In this instance it's clear there's no effort to understand her perspective, and thus, the op is afraid now of some bias. Why? Because no effort was made to understand a colleague's perspective. In general when you deal with people, empathy is a very powerful tool and is rarely used.

Comment: "This, generally speaking, is not as helpful as people imagine it to be. Unsolicited criticism is rarely taken well." The answer to this is to be more open to critical feedback, not for people to stop giving it. People should, in general, be more introspective as well. I consider criticism from all sources, even from people who are rude. Even if the criticism they offer is wrong, I can often find ways to improve because of the feedback. I find "empathy" to be unhelpful, as it doesn't help me cut past my feelings and get to the reality; it's often not even genuine, which grates on me.

Comment: This answer mischaracterizes the interaction as unsolicited advice. It would have been advice if I hadn't been affected but I was. This was *feedback*. Like if someone walked on my foot, I would give them the feedback that it hurts and ask them to step off; it's not like I randomly advise a person not to step on other people's feet.

Comment: The general analysis of this answer is correct, but its thrust is all wrong. The answer to feeling attacked and belittled by genuine critical feedback is to work on seeing past those feelings. Everywhere in life and specifically in a job with responsibility, your own feelings are just unimportant. Free constructive advice is valueable, and if you want to be successful at what you do you need to take advantage of this ressource.

Comment: "from the perspective of a woman, who is new at her job and potentially struggling; to have a man just step in and start telling you what your faults are and how you can do better, feels... awkward" -> So basically, because she is a woman, no man can actually criticize her. That's going to be hard to improve in a field with mostly men... And don't forget that OP is really senior compared to her. It's not coming from a random junior.

Comment: The Forbes article should be understood as describing a statistical phenomenon, i.e., most people are likely to take criticism this way. The author's implication seems to be that one should avoid giving criticism, but this does not follow. People who can't take constructive criticism are unlikely to succeed anyway, so how they react doesn't matter.

Comment: @qoba Just because some people were wrong in coming to you and complaining about someone not your subordinate (her) doesn't make it right for you to offer unsolicited criticism. What they did was basically venting. You've haven't initiated the wrong thing, but you've continued it instead of stopping. Which is the same thing for someone at the receiving end.

Comment: @TKK This answer is not about the criticism part, it's about the unsolicited part. The Forbes article is not about criticism at all, it's about advice.

Answer (score 24):

To me, you did good. You had some people complain, and being a senior, you thought to give advice to your junior colleague about it. She did not see it as such.

There are many reasons why that would be the case, from defense mechanism, her own bias, etc.

The question is what to do from now on, and my advice there would be: do nothing more on that topic. You are not her report, and thus aren't responsible for her. If people complain about it, and want to make it a formal complain, you can redirect them to her report and/or HR. If they just want to vent, it might be acceptable to hear it out. So long as you, yourself do not waste too much time on it.

And specifically, to your colleague, you could answer something along the lines of

> I am sorry you feel that way. I can only assure you that was not my aim, and thought you might profit from some feedback. However if that feedback is unwelcome, then I won't bring it up anymore.

Try to keep to the point, but also show that you went beyond your job to try to be helpful. But that you had no interest, and will drop it, since she obviously did not want the advice you offered.

Comment: I would additionally point out exactly as OP did to us here those parts of gathering the pattern confirmation that show it wasn't prejudiced (i.e. other people in similar situation - in this case women also contributed and reported the pattern).

Answer (score 5):

From the situation you described, it sounds as if you already made every effort possible to avoid accidentally giving the impression that there were prejudices in your remarks. Unfortunately, if the person you are speaking to is in a minority gender, age, religion etc. for your particular workplace, there is always that risk.

- You waited to see if a pattern emerged. If, in an office with an even mix of men and women, that the comments were (for example) only coming from the men, then there would have been cause for further concern. You emphasised that the feedback came from male AND female colleagues.
- You avoided describing the colleague personally, avoiding even a passing reference to subjects that may show bias. If you had said something like *"a woman like you shouldn't be nagging people to work on extra projects"*, then your colleague would have genuine reason to suspect a bias.

If issues with the colleague persist and they must be addressed at a formal level, some companies I have worked with offer the option of setting up a meeting with someone as HR attending as a 'witness', to further ensure that the situation is resolved with no prejudices. If this colleague is indeed at the same level as you however, it may be worthwhile just forwarding the concerns to their manager. They will - more likely than you - be trained to handle these situations, and there is a good chance they may have heard the same remarks you have.

In rare cases, some colleagues may simply fall back on the argument that *"you are targeting me specifically with criticism, it must be an unrelated prejudice taking hold"*. In these extreme cases (and of course, you're confident there are no prejudices clouding your judgement), the manager or HR approach can still help put you and the colleague at ease.

Comment: Are women are a "minority gender"? I'm pretty sure they outnumber men at this point...

Comment: @jpmc26 Not in the company we talk about.

Comment: I originally wrote "for your particular workplace" for that reason.

Comment: @dwizum I too would hope feedback isn't automatically discredited for those reasons. Indeed, in many scenarios, the point probably wouldn't even need to be made if the colleague didn't suspect they were being singled out for such a reason.

Comment: It should be noted that - dire as it is- women (on average) are prejudiced against women displaying  "man-like" behaviour as well. Being assertive is still considered favourable in a man, but not a woman, by both genders.

Comment: @jpmc26 "minority gender, age, religion etc. *for your particular workplace*..."

Comment: @Marianne013 thanks, I think that's a good point. I was very reluctant to let that be a consideration at all but I think it does help that there was feedback from multiple folks...

Comment: @Kozaky Hm. Would you agree that even in an environment where men are in the minority, it's very unlikely that they'll feel like their coworkers are being sexist when receiving criticism?

Answer (score 4):

> I felt like I owed this colleague to share the feedback

OK, nice you want to improve things.

> I said things like "in this case, ...", nothing at all like "you're being too aggressive.

Let us assume the ideas were civil and not biased.

Yet as a *colleague*, it is not your role to provide unsolicited significant negative feedback.

---

Instead, consider before presenting such ideas to a *colleague*, **ask** if she wanted some ideas concerning the situations.

If yes, proceed as you did.  If not a terse explanation, seeking affirmation before continuing.

Without a clear yes, move on.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is down voted. This seems very sensible

Answer (score 2):

Giving feedback is distinct from giving advice: feedback is information about events (concrete information, not opinion), while advice is a suggestion of what to do.

If you are careful to strictly give feedback - e.g. "apparently you had a conversation about xxx with a colleague, who has reported to me yyy about how they feel about you as a result of that conversation" - your feedback is pure information and, in principle, should not sound prejudiced. I say 'should' because it is easy to accidentally introduce your own opinion about the incident, often unconsciously, and that opinion can make your feedback sound prejudiced, judgemental, etc.

When you give advice it may seem wise to you - but that is because it arises from your own mental construct of the situation.  Every person's perspective on things is, of course, different; your advice can and most likely will, therefore, be received as not taking into account reality as the recipient sees things. It can fail as not making sense, not addressing the real problem ... or as being sexist, prejudiced, etc.

My advice, therefore, is "don't give advice" :).

OK, I couldn't resist that one, even if it doesn't help at all.

The approach I prefer is "feedback with enquiry", not giving advice. The feedback, I've addressed; the enquiry is a tool that can help the other person explore their reality - illuminated by the topic of your question(s). When you choose your questions with the strong intent that they are to help the other person (a) discover their own blind spots, (invalid) assumptions, prejudices, etc. and (b) gain freedom from them, then the questions will make a difference.

Now, it can take a great deal of carefulness (and, when necessary, compassion) to ask questions that are useful and that don't push the other person into a corner. But, if you have another colleague, or friend, with whom you can explore the questions you think would make a difference without being offensive - you can get feedback that may prove useful.

One aspect of the carefulness is to be clear with yourself that you are not trying to fix or change anything and you are not trying to prove a point: what you need to be committed to do is empowering the other person to discover (not 'receive from you', but discovered in their own thinking ... by exploring your questions) ideas that, when they take them into account, will have an improved result in their interactions with other people.

Answer (score 1):

Elephant in the room: If you are not this person's manager, why are people coming to you to discuss her performance?  This speaks somewhat to her manager's deficiencies as a manager, if her colleagues go to you, rather than to her manager, to complain about her performance.  You should probably raise this as a concern with her manager's manager, that her manager is not managing to properly manage.  Following this, you should, in a way that doesn't come off as cold and uncaring, but urge the people complaining to you to complain to her manager instead, because you have no authority to do anything about it.

Or perhaps these are not formal "complaints", as it were, but just office gossip.  In which case, I think perhaps you should have shared it in a less formal way.  If you have a friendly repartee with this colleague, simply mention to her over lunch one day about some of the things you've heard.  From the way it may have come off, it may have sounded to her like you were trying to do her boss's work when you had no such authority, and to be frank she's probably right.

Alright, now that we've addressed the elephant in the room, let's assume for whatever reason that you are the correct person to report to.  Now, the issue seems to be that you told her about these issues others are having with her, and you asked her to rectify her behaviour, and you gave her particular, well-detailed action items to follow to try to repair her reputation.  As far as I'm concerned, that's all you can do.  Don't pursue the issue any further.  If she wants to gossip about how you're sexist or whatever, then let her do so.  One of two things are going to happen:

1) She will not change her ways and her reputation will continue to decline and diminish, and she will eventually professionally implode.  You did what you could to prevent this, the rest is not your problem.  As the saying goes, you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink.

The other option is a bit more involved.  The problem is that as a majority (male, I presume white), it is a very serious issue to be labelled an "-ist" by a minority in a professional (work) environment).  Basically, if a woman calls you a sexist, in the current environment, if you don't believe the woman's accusation even without proof, then you risk being labelled as a sexist as well (see also racist if the person is POC, homophobic if the person is LGBT, islamophobic if the person is Muslim, etc), and, most importantly, the legal implications of this as a legal entity.  To which I am referring not to you, but to your company.  If she lodges a formal complaint with HR against your good-natured attempt to put her back on track and calls you a sexist, it's in the company's best legal interest to take corrective action against you, even if she is completely fabricating the story.  To mitigate this, I would stay away from her completely.  Do not talk to her, do not associate with her.  If you have the need to work together, insist that all communication be done over a written medium (email, Slack, etc) or via communication by an impartial third party (e.g. her/your manager).  If you are friends outside of work, I'm sorry to say but your friendship is over.  If she asks why, feel free to explain to her that you do not feel comfortable being labelled as a sexist, and you would like all communication preserved for posterity just in case.

If other colleagues continue to come to you with complaints, I would simply write down the names and brief descriptions of the complaints, and when you have enough of them, dump them on the desk of some HR person, or her manager, and let come what may.  Since you have no authority over her, you can't do anything except come to her as a friend and ask her to shape up, which you have done and she has rejected.  In which case, imo she has forfeited her privilege to a warning, and the next step is to report your findings to the people who do have such authority, and if this ends up in her being fired, it's neither your concern nor your problem.

Answer (score 1):

"I had discussed the situation with this person's manager, who had encouraged me to share feedback and help coach her rather than he having to do it with secondhand information."

This is unacceptable on the part of the manager.  Having the three of you in the room would have been iffy to begin with, but just you and her without management at all is indefensible.

Of course she feels like a man is trying to shut her up.  That is literally what just happened!  You, a random man who is organizationally at the same level as her, is telling her she is wrong and needs to stop.  You are not this person's manager and your conversation with her was highly inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> I  held back until I saw more of a pattern. [...] I said things like "in this case, you did this, and the outcome was that, here's how it could become a problem for you in the long term, and here's a couple things you can consider doing in the future"

Don't. The likely problem here is she might have interpreted this as you mansplaining her what she ought to be doing.

Try something more like this instead, and do so *shortly* after you notice the problematic behavior:

> If I may point something out, when you [behavior], then [outcome].

Or even more ideally:

> May I point something out? [wait for yes; and iff yes:] When you [behavior], then [outcome].

Don't make it personal; if she goes defensive, keep the focus on the behavior, and let go if she takes it personally to the point of growing restless.

If you were her boss, you'd likely add something like: "Can you try something different in the future?" But you're not her boss, so let her decide whether to do so or not; and if she says you may not point it out, keep your cool and let her fall on her face.

And then leave it at that. Let her figure out what she could do instead. In particular, don't do anything she might think of as mansplaining. However welcome you think the shortcut you gave her is, she'll likely resist it; whereas if she's the one figuring it out she'll eventually change.

Aside: this isn't sex-specific. The same also applies for male colleagues.

Also: her boss should have delivered this feedback himself, but that's a separate problem.

Answer (score -3):

Here's how I am seeing things: She's obviously using the *man vs. woman* argument just so that she can get out of this.

I mean, this is work; everyone here is working for the same goal and everyone should do their job right no matter your gender. You are a senior, and it means that you basically have more experience, and everyone as a junior, no matter what's their gender, should listen to what a more experienced person has to say and also no matter who the senior's gender.

Consider yourself as a manager or HR and she did a terrible mistake that can cost a fortune, would you say: You're a woman so we won't say anything? Of course not. It's your job to give pointers if you're a senior, and if you're a manager you will be in a critical position to take decisions about work and the whole company.

I mean, don't think too much about it and that *You say this because I'm a woman*, *You biased to men*, etc... This is a discussion about work. It has nothing to do with him or her, so don't make it a personal problem. Imagine that the team quit because of her; can she pay the damage or replace the work of how many people? Obviously NO.

So my advice is this: If you're just a senior colleague when you talk to her, try to point out that this is related to work, and it's nothing personal or related to gender, or you can try to talk to the manager so that he can talk to her about this because that's obviously his job, to make sure that everything is OK and make decisions about that. If you're the manager then you have every right to point out if something is wrong with the way she's doing her job or her behaviour ... People leave their jobs just because of the environment, so it would be a huge loss if good people were lost because of someone's behaviour.

Good luck dealing with this situation.

Comment: Not sure what your comment has to do with anything. For example, you write " everyone here is working for the same goal and everyone should do their job right no matter your gender" although OP clearly stated women do experience problems in his industry.

Comment: "She's obviously using the man vs. woman argument just so that she can get out of this." - to me that is not necessarily obvious.

Comment: That is not obvious to me either. I don't think she is trying to ignore the feedback.

Comment: How is it not obvious ? When your senior tells you that you did something wrong, the first think you'll think about is asking him what's wrong, and not telling him that he's telling you you're wrong because you're a woman. Everyone can make mistakes and this is something that everyone should accept, if you can't even start be accepting your own mistakes and try to fix them then what benefits can you bring to the company ? How can you develop yourself ?
Instead of asking listening to guidance from a senior she's telling him I am a woman that's why you criticize me ?